# Get Animator for LayoutTransition from R.anim XML

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, layouttransition

I have been searching for a while and can't seem to find anything useful on this topic. Is it possible to set the animation for a LayoutTransition to an animation declared in XML? The default animation will fade the view being added or removed from a ViewGroup and shift the other views accordingly, but I want to have a view slide in or out to the side. I have tried the following to set an Animator from Animation object, but it doesn't seem like it did anything. I just set the fields I found to be common across the two types, but really I have no idea what I am doing with animation.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setLayoutTransition() {
    LayoutTransition transition = new LayoutTransition();

    Animation appearing = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    Animator aa = transition.getAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING);
    aa.setDuration(appearing.getDuration());
    aa.setInterpolator(appearing.getInterpolator());

    Animation disappearing = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    Animator bb = transition.getAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
    bb.setDuration(disappearing.getDuration());
    bb.setInterpolator(disappearing.getInterpolator());

    transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, aa);
    transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, bb);

    dashboardLayout.setLayoutTransition(transition);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Actually, `Animation` and `Animator` are different parts of the API, targeted at slightly different tasks.

`Animator`s are for value animations, `Animation`s are for view animations. So, an `Animator` can animate whatever property an object has but you have to specify what and how. `Animation`s are less flexible but have some ready recipes for views.

So, in your case, you can either define `Animator`s from scratch or manually start `Animation`s on views involved in layout changes -- the latter is possible but I sense it would cause way more hassle than the former.

Go with `Animator`s, you can easily define them in `.xml` files too, here's [all about it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)